# project type is not showing in python when i try to create a new project

Tags: python, django, windows, pycharm

I am using pycharm community edition. I just installed django3.1rc1 version. I can create a new project with command prompt but when i click on new project in pycharm, the project type row at left is not showing. can anyone please tell me how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It because **Pycharm Community edition** doesn't support Django. if you want Django support than you should try **PyCharm Professional Edition**
[Here's the professional vs community edition comparison.](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html)

Comment: Thanks. So in the community edition, I have to create a project through terminal or command prompt ?

Comment: Yeah! you need to create a new project using terminal/command prompt. **Pycharm community**  doesn't even support **js/css**. So I recommend you to use **vscode** instead of using community edition if you don't wanna pay for PyCharm professional.